# Visibility of links with uppercase letters in protocol section is inconsistent

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

Any link is visible in post preview despite of case in protocol section. But only links where protocol in lowercase are visible in result.

- Here is the link with uppercase letter in protocol section:  (visible only in preview mode, just click on "edit" under the post to see)
- Here is the link with all lowercase letters in protocol: http://google.com (visible everywhere)

Both links are actually refer to the same site.

Original bug report was reported on ruSO: [Различие в парсинге ссылок браузером и сервером](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7742/176217)