# "Save and copy changes" button copies not only changes!

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-copying

The button <kbd>Save and copy changes to all public communities</kbd> from profile page copies not only changes from my [ruSO profile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217?tab=profile) to all my public communities profiles.

> [image]

In partucular, I've only changed visible name, but about block has been copied   to my [MSE profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911?tab=profile) as well. It looks empty, but here is buggy invisible link exists: [Visibility of links with uppercase letters in protocol section is inconsistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314823/339911)